# Ajax Jquery - simple request does not answer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

It's been some time I am looking for an answer but as far as today, nobody found :

I am trying to implement some ajax method to post some comments on a webpage. I use the ajax method like such :

```
<button id="my-btn">Make an Ajax request!</button>

<script >
  $('#my-btn').click(function() {
    var comment = $('#id1').val();   
    var m = {$id2};
     var data = new Array();
     data[0]= comment;
    data[1]= m;

    $.post('{$postURL}', data, function(callback_data){

    alert('hello');

    });

  });
</script>
```

where m = {$id2}; is due to a smarty variable.

The `alert('hello')` works, but the php code is not processed : `{$postURL}` requires a method `comment(){$comment = $_POST[$data[0]]; $m = $_POST[$data[1]];...}`.

So, `postURL` is like : `"index.php?post=comment"`, and the method is `comment()`.

Of course, when I replace `{$postURL}` by `"index.php?post=comment"`, nothing happens in the sense that I still have the `alert('hello')` message but the method `comment()` doesn't process anything.

Is this method evenc called ? Or is there a wrong syntax such that `$_POST[$data[0]]` and `$_POST[$data[1]]` aren(t recognized bt the comment() method.

The way index.php works is to redirect : to a another php page, call it mypage.php where we can find the `comment()` method.

Moreover, something very weird : when I corrupt `$.post("{$postURL}"` by `$.post("{$whatever}"`, I still have a `alert('hello')` message ! And weirder, when I put an alert(callback_data); inside the callback function, I get a huge alert message, which consists of my whole php code...

In a precedent question, I was told to put some delimiters because of Smarty like so :

```
$('#my-btn').click(function() {ldelim}
    var comment = $('#id1').val();   
    var m = {$id2};
    var data = {ldelim}
      comment: $('#id1').val(),
      m: {$id2}
    {rdelim};
    $.post("{$postURL}", data, function(callback_data){ldelim}
      alert('hello');
    {rdelim});
  {rdelim});
```

But, nothing changed,

Anybody has an idea ?

Best, Newben

Comment: You're able to alert the PHP code? It seems like you somehow haven't set PHP to process the file.

Comment: Check your generated html document first. If everything is ok there, the problem is in your php code.

Comment: Indeed, when I put some random redirection page in method() (or echo('blabla');), it seems not to be processed

Comment: In fact, I am sure of my php code, because when I call method() by a <form action= "{$postURL}">, it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be that you are passing data as javascript array, but it should be a map or string as mentioned [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
Try this :

```
<script >
  $('#my-btn').click(function() {
    var comment = $('#id1').val();   
    var m = {$id2};
       $.post('<?php echo $postURL ?>', {0 : comment,1 : m}, function(callback_data){
            alert('hello');
       });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I tried and I got an internal server error. But, the fact is that I tried to echo something in the method() and nothing happened. And again when I tried to alert(callback_data), I got a huge message of all my code. To be precise, the file index.php processes a class in a  n another php page, where the method comment() is. It seems that the post ajax request doesn't recognize the php code, but takes it into a plain text...

Comment: What output(json/array) are you exactly returning from your php method? And try using console(callback_data) in script and also put echo "test"; die; in php method to check the code control.

Comment: The comment() method only stores the posted comment in the database. So when i put console(callback_data); i get nothing and I loose the alert('hello') message, and the echo test doesn't work. It seems that the php is not read

Comment: Try the updated code now. I have changed {$POSTUrL} into <?php echo $posturl;?>

Comment: If it can helps : when i put a $.post('index.php'..., and if I call for a alert('callback_data'), I get a huge message of all my code. Soi, it seems that the php code towards wich the $.post sends, is considered as a plain text ! I really don't understand

Comment: Precisely, the alert message is so huge, I can only see the first lines, that are the html code of my page (upper-page perhaps more but i can't see)